# Conditions for ball to retrace after colliding with wall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, projectile

When a ball collides to wall,what would be some conditions for it to retrace or atleast return to from where it was thrown.

When thought about it I was getting a result that ball has to collide with the wall before it reaches max height of its trajectory.( I am not sure about it at all)

But what would be an actual solution to it

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision it explains at least the most basic things. In your case, the wall has much more mass than the ball, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

### Let's look at the stricter requirement first, where we want the ball to re-trace its initial path exactly.

In Newtonian physics the equations of motion are all time-reversible (ignoring air-resistance), meaning that all the physics works the same if we play this movie forward or backwards. Knowing this, you can see that for the ball to take the same path after the re-bound as before, we would want the velocity of the ball directly after it hits the wall to be the same as just before it hits, but pointed in the opposite direction. It might help to imagine someone dropping a ball from a high place, and then someone throwing the ball back upwards with the same exact speed: you would expect the ball to return to precisely the same place as long as the direction of throw is in 180° from the velocity the ball had when it hit the ground.

Knowing this ([and again ignoring any energy losses from when the ball hits the wall](https://xkcd.com/669/)), it might make sense that would want the ball to hit the wall at a 90° angle. If there is a glancing blow, the ball will not be perfectly reversing it's direction, and so the ball will necessarily follow a different return path. If there are any energy losses at any point in the process, you won't be able to get home the same way.

### Now, relaxing the condition that the path is identical

If we again assume no losses due to air-resistance or the ball bouncing off the wall, the horizontal velocity of the ball is identical but reversed before and after it hits the wall. Additionally, its vertical velocity is identical and in the same direction before and after it hits the wall (e.g. the ball will continue rising if it was rising before it hit the wall). You might be able to see that this poses a problem for getting the ball back to where it started, since it has the same horizontal distance to travel back to you, but now it will have a different amount of hang-time to make that return-trip. If the ball was glancing upwards when it hit the wall, it still has to complete the journey to the top of it's arc before it starts coming down again. And all that time, it has been moving horizontally further and further away from the wall. The upshot of this is that when energy is conserved, you cannot have a glancing shot return to it's original position.

### Returning to the real world...

If any of these idealized conditions are not true (the wall isn't straight up and down, there is wind resistance, the ball deforms when it hits the wall and so loses a bit of energy, etc etc.) there will be solutions to this problem that involve a glancing shot, which is why in real life you see this type of behavior all the time. And indeed you are right that if we are losing energy in the bounce, we want an upwards-glancing shot, since the velocity loss on the rebound will need to be made-up with extra hang-time. An exact solution would require modeling ball-deformation which is outside the scope of this question, though I imagine you could get a pretty accurate closed-form solution by assuming some reasonable [coefficient of restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution), and solving for the velocity the ball has right after colliding with the wall.